# why the dart function did not return the sub function result

Tags: flutter, dart

I am now using this functon to fetch new music in flutter:

```
class QuietPlayQueueInterceptor extends PlayQueueInterceptor {
  @override
  Future<List<MusicMetadata>> fetchMoreMusic(BackgroundPlayQueue queue, PlayMode playMode) async {
    if (queue.queueId == kFmPlayQueueId) {
      final musics = await (neteaseRepository!.getPersonalFmMusicsFromQueue() as FutureOr<List<Music>>);
      final musicListExt= musics.toMetadataList();
      return musicListExt;
    }
    return super.fetchMoreMusic(queue, playMode);
  }
}
```

and this is the function `getPersonalFmMusicsFromQueue` define:

```
  Future<List<Music>?> getPersonalFmMusicsFromQueue() async {
    if(fmPlayQueue.isEmpty){
        return getPersonalFmMusics();
    }else{
     final Music music = fmPlayQueue.first;
      final List<Music> musics = List.empty(growable: true);
      musics.add(music);
      return Future.value(musics);
    }
  }
```

what makes me confusing is that the `getPersonalFmMusicsFromQueue` function did not return any result. I make a breakpoint on the line `final musicListExt= musics.toMetadataList();` but did not hited. The console is no error output. where am I doing wrong? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`getPersonalFmMusics` looks asynchronous? Perhaps you're not awaiting

```dart
Future<List<Music>?> getPersonalFmMusicsFromQueue() async {
  if(fmPlayQueue.isEmpty){
      return await getPersonalFmMusics();
  }
  // ...
```

I would also advise against casting unless you're sure you need it. Instead, have the return type of `getPersonalFmMusicsFromQueue` return a `FutureOr`

```dart
(neteaseRepository!.getPersonalFmMusicsFromQueue() as FutureOr<List<Music>>); // Remove FutureOr<List<Music>>

// and make the function signature instead look like this:
FutureOr<List<Music>> getPersonalFmMusicsFromQueue(); // Force unwrapping with a `!` but also throwing proper exceptions when null.
```

The reason being is that casting usually hides errors the compiler would otherwise be warning you about.

Another idea I have if the above isn't the issue is the `.first` call.

```dart
final Music music = fmPlayQueue.first;
```

If this is a `first` getter on a stream then that need to be awaited and it likely isn't working because it's just indefinitely waiting for the stream to output a value.